# Connect Tibco with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tibco

I am searching some solution to push and pop messages from and to Tibco EMS queue. I found solutions from almost every language but not with JavaScript or NodeJs.

I need to connect with NodeJs but JavaScript solution will also work.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is expected that you have fully researched the issue and have made an attempt to solve it before posting a question here. When you created your account here, it was suggested that you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) guidelines. Please do so, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What kinds of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and *edit your question* so that conforms to the site guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/JensWalter/node-ems. This plugin is experimental and buggy, but this might be a good starting point